# Cloudfront: How to test Path Pattern matching without deploying any changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn

I just need a way to test my path pattern for cloudfront first before saving the behavior for the pattern because I noticed that it's taking more than a few minutes for the changes to be deployed. Basically, the pattern that I want to implement is for urls like:

`https://<domain>/some_users_slug/index.html`

`https://<domain>/some_users_slug/some_uuid/index.html`

and the equivalent pattern that I have so far are:

`/?*/index.html`

`/?*/?*/index.html`

I'm totally new to cloudfront so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly that's why I wanted a way to test the patterns I have before I save the behaviors again.

Comment: This would be a simple tool for AWS to write and a nice resources to have. I don't know why they haven't provided it yet.